# ¿Cómo hacer un delay en c# sin detener el programa?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017

resulta que últimamente he estado desarrollando una calculadora en c# con windows form. En la calculadora se comprueban las excepciones y cuando ocurre una mi idea es que se muestre error en el textbox y después de medio segundo que el texto del textbox sea igual al operador. Me recomendaron usar Thread.Sleep() pero eso detiene todo el programa y el mensaje de error no se muestra.
La sección del código:

```
TextBox.Text = "Error";
Thread.Sleep(500);
operador = save;
operador = operador.Replace("*", "x");
operador = operador.Replace("/", "÷");
TextBox.Text = operador;
TextBox.Focus();
TextBox.SelectionStart = TextBox.Text.Length;
```

Comment: Medio segundo es un intervalo muy corto, por eso da la impresión de que no se muestra el error. ¿Por qué no pruebas subirlo a unos 5 segundos, Thread.Sleep(5000);?

Comment: @JYass Thread.Sleep se ejecuta en el mismo hilo que el de la UI, subirlo a 5000 solo bloquearía la UI por 5 segundos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero que utilices hilos para correr en otro hilo de proceso cambio de valor del TextBox, y así obtener ese efecto sin que quede bloqueado todo el programa.

Aquí un ejemplo como podrías utilizarlo:

```
//SETEAMOS EL ERROR DENTRO DE TEXTBOX
TextBox.Text = "Error";

//ASIGNAMOS LA EXPRESIÓN LAMBDA A LA VARIABLE cambiarValorText
//, PARA QUE EL HILO LO EJECUTE
Action cambiarValorText = () =>
        {
            //VERIFICAMOS SI PODEMOS TENER ACCESO A LOS CONTROLES
            //QUE EL PROCESO PRINCIPAL CREÓ
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                //ASIGNAMOS A ACCION LA TAREA A RELIZAR
                Action accion = () =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    operador = save;
                    operador = operador.Replace("*", "x");
                    operador = operador.Replace("/", "÷");
                    TextBox.Text = operador;
                    TextBox.Focus();
                    TextBox.SelectionStart = TextBox.Text.Length;
                };

                //INVOCAMOS LA TAREA accion
                this.Invoke(accion);
            }
        };

        //CREAMOS EL HILO PARA QUE EJECUTE EN PARALELO EL METODO cambiarValorText
        var t = new System.Threading.Thread(new ThreadStart(cambiarValorText));
        t.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Solución mas corta:

```
async void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try {
           // codigo aquí
    }
    catch{
        TextBox.Text = "Error";
        await Task.Delay(500);
        operador = save;
        operador = operador.Replace("*", "x");
        operador = operador.Replace("/", "÷");
        TextBox.Text = operador;
        TextBox.Focus();
        TextBox.SelectionStart = TextBox.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

Agregas async al metodo asociado al evento que lanza el codigo, y ya puedes ejecutar de forma asíncrona el "sleep" (Delay)

EDIT: Requiere de .Net Framework versión 4.5 o mayor.